# About Postal outside of ASP.NET

Tags: model-view-controller, schedule, postal

I'm using Postal library for sending emails in an ASP.NET MVC5 Web project. It works fine when called from a controller. However, I planned a number of jobs to send emails using fluentScheduler. And I am calling a method that sends emails using the instructions here http://aboutcode.net/postal/outside-aspnet.html.

But I still get the same exception everytime I run the background task.

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here is the stack:

```
    at Glimpse.AspNet.AspNetFrameworkProvider.get_HttpRequestStore()
   at Glimpse.Core.Framework.Factory.<>c__DisplayClass5.<InstantiateRuntimePolicyStrategy>b__4()
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensions.AlternateMethodContextExtensions.TryProceedWithTimer(IAlternateMethodContext context, TimerResult& timerResult)
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context)
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IViewEngineProxy.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClass6.<FindView>b__4(IViewEngine e)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName)
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.CreateView(String viewName, ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName)
   at Postal.EmailService.CreateMailMessage(Email email)
   at Postal.EmailService.Send(Email email)
   at Postal.Email.Send()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at Bay3.Helpers.EmailHelper.FollowerEmail(String to, String link, String articleName, String lang) in e:\_TFS2\Bay3\Bay3\Helpers\EmailHelper.cs:line 39
```

I hope that someone had the same problem before

Comment: Please read the question carefully, it is about postal library for mvc.